# Can not see the MobileFirst Operations Console via browser

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-mobilefirst-windows

After installed the develop kit (version 8), I start the console via the script run.sh. However, I couldn't see the details after log on, just like the picture attached.[the screen just like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ui4L.png)

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed in the latest ifix that is released on 2017/06/06. Please apply the latest ifix